# Checking array count and then adding condition to add "and" to last array output

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I have successfully create conditions which check the array count. Everything I have is working, but I am trying to figure out how to configure it so that if the results are:

```
1, 2, 3
```

I want it to be:

```
1, 2 and 3
```

How can I do this?

```
$proposal_type_arr = $_POST['prop-type'];
$proposal_type_count = count($proposal_type_arr);
if ($proposal_type_count == 1) {
    $proposal_type = implode("", $proposal_type_arr);
} 
else if ($proposal_type_count == 2) {
    $proposal_type = implode(" and ", $proposal_type_arr);
}
else if ($proposal_type_count > 2) {
    $proposal_type = implode(", ", $proposal_type_arr);
}
```

Comment: hope my post will help you out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_pop()` to grab the last element in the array. When combined with `implode()` you'd be able to cut down on the conditional logic.

Example:

```
$proposal_type_arr = $_POST['prop-type'];
$proposal_type_count = count( $proposal_type_arr );

if ( $proposal_type_count > 1 ) {
    $last_el = array_pop( $proposal_type_arr );
    $proposal_type = implode( ', ', $proposal_type_arr ) . ' and ' . $last_el;
} else {
    $proposal_type = current( $proposal_type_arr );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on the better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792659) `sample array taken`

```
elseif ($proposal_type_count > 2)
{
    $temp=$proposal_type_arr[$proposal_type_count-1];//getting last element
    unset($proposal_type_arr[$proposal_type_count-1]);//unsetting last element
    $proposal_type = implode(", ", $proposal_type_arr);
    echo $proposal_type.= " and $temp";//attaching last element with "and "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_pop to pop the last element out,  and if you want to just keep the first two, use array_slice(). Then use implode to trans array to string.

```
$end =  array_pop(&$array);
echo implode(',', $array) . ' and ' . $end;
```